# Can not figure out why jQuery UI 1.10 does not honor neither ajaxSettings.error nor jqXHR.fail when working with tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I upgraded jQuery UI library to 1.10 version. According to documentation the code below suppose to work, but it does not. Please tell me if it is me doing the mistake somewhere or their new jQuery UI library is just full of bugs.

If you want to try the code below live I set up [the test link.](http://cl-t029-082cl.privatedns.com/public/test.html)

The tabs will pull the following JSON strings:

For "GOOD Json" tab:

```
{
 "html":"This is HTML text from good Json",
 "msgWarning":"This is message text from good Json",
 "msgSuccess":"","misc":[]
}
```

For "BAD Json" tab:

```
{
 "html":"This is HTML text from bad Json",
 "msgWarning":"This is message text from bad Json",
 "msgSuccess":"","misc":[]
}blablabla
```

You will notice that that the tab "JSON Good" loads just fine. The tab "JSON Bad" will never load as JSON is malformed. In previous versions of jQuery UI I used the ERROR setting for trapping this kind of errors. But the new code just never triggered on this error, no matter what I try.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;" >

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myprofileShow()
    {
        $("#tabs-myProfile").show();
        $("#tabs-myProfile").tabs();
        $('<li><a href="http://cl-t029-082cl.privatedns.com/public/json-good.html">JSON Good</a></li>').appendTo("#tabs-myProfile .ui-tabs-nav");
        $('<li><a href="http://cl-t029-082cl.privatedns.com/public/json-bad.html">JSON BAD</a></li>').appendTo("#tabs-myProfile .ui-tabs-nav");
        $("#tabs-myProfile").tabs("refresh");
        $("#tabs-myProfile").tabs('destroy');

        $("#tabs-myProfile").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.panel.html('working...');

                ui.ajaxSettings.dataType = "json";

                ui.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function(data) {
                    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    return  jsonData.msgWarning + jsonData.html;
                };

                ui.jqXHR.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //do nothing
                });

               ui.ajaxSettings.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    ui.panel.html('<b>Something went wrong test 1</b>');
                };

                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html('<b>Something went wrong test 2</b>');
                });

                ui.jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR) {
                    ui.panel.html('<b>Something went wrong test 3</b>');
                });
            }
        });

        $("#tabs-myProfile").tabs({selected: 1});
    }
</script>

<div id="tabs-myProfile" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    myprofileShow();
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, jsonp requests do not trigger error handlers.

Comment: Not sure what does it have to do with JSONP. I did not mention making AJAX calls to other domains

Comment: I made that assumption based on jQuery UI has nothing to do with error callbacks happening and the only change that recently happened that would change the functionality you are seeing is jQuery 1.9 no longer firing errors for jsonp requests.

Comment: To rephrase my original question from above: how do I catch the fact that JSON was returned malformed?

Comment: If the json is malformed, your console will receive an error on this line: `var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);` your option at that point is to try catch it, and if it's caught, return the data unchanged.

Comment: :-)  Let's rephrase again:
Is it possible to rewrite the following original code in 1.10 without using try/catch block?

    $( "#ajax-tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html("Err on AJAX call");
            },
            dataFilter: function(result){
                var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                return  data.html;
            }
        }
    });

Comment: Stupid formatting does not work

Comment: failed to copy paste, let me try that again... Probably not, because the error is happening in `$.parseJSON()` which doesn't have an error callback.

Comment: Add `\`` before and after it, or put it in a pastebin.

Comment: You lost me with your last comment. In the code prior to 1.10, the error was trapped by jquery ajax call if I set 'error' callback in Tabs() function. Presently, documentation claims that it is still possible but in practice it never does and allows to proceed further to the code where $.parseJSON line is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the dataFilter() function should be understood as explained 
[here:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> A function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest.This is a pre-filtering function to sanitize the response. You should return the sanitized data.

Seems that the code within this function is beyond the scope of the Ajax exception handling, and throws an exception out on the console instead:
A look at the console reveals:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b

which has been triggerd by your code line:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
```

I assume that when you get rid of your dataFilter function and let jQuery *implicitly* handle the JSON parsing (which should happen automatically when your dataType is set to 'json') then the Ajax exception handling ( through error() / fail() ) will work as expected.

Comment: Nope. Tried that scenario before. jQuery is not honoring it anymore. In the previous versions filter was applied after JSON validation. Presently it seems like JSON validation is not performed at all.

Comment: Sorry to clarify. It does honor it if you are using it outside of Tabs functionality. But if you try to pass parameters through tabs function, that flow no longer works. As a metter of fact I've never been able to generate any kind of error that would be catched in .fail callback.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [here](http://wadewalkeronline.com/post/2013/05/29/jQuery-UI-110-Tabs-Dynamically-load-User-Control.aspx).

```
$("#MainContent_contentArea").tabs({
activate: function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.newPanel.is(':empty')) {
        ui.newPanel.append("<div class='tab-loading'>...Loading...<br /><img src='Images/ajax-loader.gif' /></div>");
    };
}
, show: {
    efect: 'slideDown',
    duration: 500
}
, beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
    alert('beforeLoad');
    ui.ajaxSettings.accepts = { json: "application/json, text/javascript" };
    ui.ajaxSettings.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    ui.ajaxSettings.type = "POST";
    ui.ajaxSettings.dataTypes[0] = "json";

    ui.jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", ui.ajaxSettings.contentType);

    ui.jqXHR.error(function (data) { alert('error'); alert(data.status + ' - ' + data.statusText) });
    ui.jqXHR.success(function (data) { alert('success'); alert(data) });
}
```

});

Comment: Don't use `activate` event for the loading indicator, `activate` triggers after the animation is complete. The `beforeLoad` event is perfect for showing the loading indicator.